# Неважно / не важно

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

*— Ваш номер я записал!*

*— Так он у меня скрыт тут.*

*— (Не)важно.*

Как написать слово категории состояния: слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

— *Ваш номер я записал!*
*— Так он у меня скрыт тут.*
*— **Неважно*** (= без разницы).

**Орфографический словарь**

**неважно,** в знач. сказ. (к *неважный*: **не имеет значения**) и *неважно*, нареч. (к *неважный*: *неважно себя чувствовать*).

**Теория**

НЕ с предикативными наречиями на О обычно может писаться **как слитно, так и раздельно**, при этом орфограмма имеет **смысловое** решение, которое во многих случаях является **авторским**.

**Примечание**

Считается, что слитное написание НЕ при утверждении противоположного признака предполагает **замену синонимом** без НЕ: *непросто (трудно) говорить об этом; непростительно обманывать друга; нехорошо оставлять людей в беде; неизвестно, что будет дальше.*

В то же время **градации признака обычно нет**, то есть формы «не является простым» и «является непростым (трудным)» по семантике совпадают.

Но тогда авторское решение связано **с логическим выделением слова при отрицании**: «***не прОсто*** говорить об этом».

Позиция наречия **в начале предложения** особенно удобна для постановки **логического ударения и раздельного написания**. Но при отсутствии ударения слово пишется **слитно**: *нетрудно, непростительно*.